# get sentence with cursor and multiple commas in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I get a sentence with multiple commas in MS Word with VBA that the cursor is in?

All the posts I've found said to get the sentence the cursor is in then use the code:

```
Selection.Sentences(1)
```

The above works well with a sentence with only 1 comma.  But if I have a sentence with multiple commas like this:

```
For example, tomorrow is Tuesday(e.g., not Wednesday) or Thursday.
```

where the cursor is set somewhere in "For example" then "Selection.Sentences(1)" returns between the bars "...(e.g.|, |n...".

I'm using the latest version of Word.  I plan on launching the code on an older version (I think 2013) that I first noticed the problem on.

Comment: It's not the multiple commas that are "choking" the result - it's the periods in the abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

This code is better suited to explain why MS didn't solve your problem than it is to actually solve it. However - depending upon your circumstances - you may like to play with it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectSentence()
    ' 30 Jan 2018

    ' list abbreviations containing periods only
    ' in sequence of their expected frequency of occurrance
    Const Abbs As String = "e.g.,f.i.,etc.,i.e."

    Dim Fun As String                       ' sentence to select
    Dim Para As Range
    Dim SelStart As Long                    ' location of selection
    Dim Sp() As String                      ' array of Abbs
    Dim Cp() As String                      ' array of encoded Abbs

    With Selection
        Set Para = .Paragraphs(1).Range
        SelStart = .Start
    End With
    Sp = Split(Abbs, ",")

    With Para
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Text = CleanString(.Text, Sp, Cp)
        Fun = ActiveDocument.Range(SelStart, SelStart + 1).Sentences(1).Text
        SelStart = InStr(.Text, Fun) + .Start - 1
        .Text = OriginalString(.Text, Cp)
        .SetRange SelStart, SelStart + Len(Fun) - 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        .Select
    End With
    Fun = Selection.Text
    Debug.Print Fun
End Sub

Private Function CleanString(ByVal Txt As String, _
                             Abbs() As String, _
                             Cp() As String) As String
    ' 30 Jan 2018

    Dim i As Integer

    ReDim Cp(UBound(Abbs))
    For i = 0 To UBound(Abbs)
        If InStr(Txt, ".") = 0 Then Exit For
        Cp(i) = AbbToTxt(Abbs(i))
        Txt = Replace(Txt, Abbs(i), Cp(i))
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve Cp(i)
    CleanString = Txt
End Function

Private Function AbbToTxt(ByVal Abb As String) As String
    ' 30 Jan 2018
    ' use a character for Chr(92) not occurring in your document.
    ' Apparently it must be a character with a code below 128.
    ' use same character as function 'AbbToTxt'
    AbbToTxt = Replace(Abb, ".", Chr(92))
End Function

Private Function OriginalString(ByVal Txt As String, _
                                Cp() As String) As String
    ' 30 Jan 2018

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(Cp) - 1
        Txt = Replace(Txt, Cp(i), TxtToAbb(Cp(i)))
    Next i
    OriginalString = Txt
End Function

Private Function TxtToAbb(ByVal Txt As String) As String
    ' 30 Jan 2018
    ' use same character as function 'AbbToTxt'
    TxtToAbb = Replace(Txt, Chr(92), ".")
End Function
```

For one, the code will only handle abbreviations which you program into it (see `Const Abbs` at the top of the code). For another, it will fail to recognise a period with dual meaning, such as "etc." found at the end of a sentence.

If you are allowed to edit the documents you work with, the better way of tackling your problem may well be to remove the offending periods with Find > Replace. After all, whoever understands "e.g." is also likely to understand "eg". Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't like the idea of replacing symbols in the document and then restoring them as there are too many things that can go wrong. One idea I had was using the regex period+white space+capital letter as the separator for the sentences. I'm sure there are some cases where this wouldn't work. I'm new to programming in VBA so I'm not sure the best way to code that.